# PureCSS Grid not centered on Firefox

Tags: css, yui-pure-css

I'm trying out [PureCSS](http://purecss.io/) for my website and it seemed like everything was going great.  I opened it up in Firefox and noticed that my content wasn't centered.

[You can view my site here.](http://trevore.com/)

The HTML/CSS is pretty simple.  If I open the Inspector tool, I can see that my `<div class="content pure-u-1 pure-u-md-3-5">` is rendered correctly at 60% width.  If that's the case, then why isn't

```
.content {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

centering my content in Firefox?  Everything works fine in Chrome.  It's been a while since I've done front-end stuff, but after some quick searches I see people still recommending `margin: 0 auto;` for centering, so I figure this has something to do with the grid framework?  I also have everything set to `box-sizing: border-box;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a rendering inconsistency between browsers.

In the framework you are using, the grid elements are set to `inline-block`. The elements need to be `block` level in order for `margin: 0 auto` to have an effect and center the elements in FireFox:

```
.content {
    margin: 0px auto;
    display: block;
}
```

The culprit in the framework styles:

```
.pure-u-1, .pure-u-1-1, .pure-u-1-2, .pure-u-1-3, .pure-u-2-3, .pure-u-1-4, .pure-u-3-4, .pure-u-1-5, .pure-u-2-5, .pure-u-3-5, .pure-u-4-5, .pure-u-5-5, .pure-u-1-6, .pure-u-5-6, .pure-u-1-8, .pure-u-3-8, .pure-u-5-8, .pure-u-7-8, .pure-u-1-12, .pure-u-5-12, .pure-u-7-12, .pure-u-11-12, .pure-u-1-24, .pure-u-2-24, .pure-u-3-24, .pure-u-4-24, .pure-u-5-24, .pure-u-6-24, .pure-u-7-24, .pure-u-8-24, .pure-u-9-24, .pure-u-10-24, .pure-u-11-24, .pure-u-12-24, .pure-u-13-24, .pure-u-14-24, .pure-u-15-24, .pure-u-16-24, .pure-u-17-24, .pure-u-18-24, .pure-u-19-24, .pure-u-20-24, .pure-u-21-24, .pure-u-22-24, .pure-u-23-24, .pure-u-24-24 {
    display: inline-block; /* Culprit */
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-rendering: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed it and your explanation makes sense. :) Will accept when it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

What I am using for centring text is as follows:

```
.content {    
    width: 50%;    
    left: 50%;    
    position: absolute;   
    margin-left: -25%;    
    text-align: center;  
}
```

It works for all of the browsers I tested out including ff

To add on: It also shrinks text when you minimize browsers window.